# To what namespace does Response.Redirect belong to?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

When i write this in a static class i get red line bellow Response:

```
  Response.Redirect("ErrorPage.aspx.aspx?Error=" + READERROR);
```

It asks me whether i have got a missing assembly. How do i fix this?

Comment: If you are using VS and the text cursor is over the underlined identifier then `control-.` (full stop) will give you options including adding a using declaration.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Namespace:** `System.Web`

**Assembly:** `System.Web` (in System.Web.dll)

But if you are defining in Static class, then I think it should be...

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(....);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this except of `Response.Redirect("SomePage.aspx");`

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("SomePage.aspx");
```

because `Response` (it is object and class is `HttpWebResponse`) is the member of `Page` class.

Answer (score 1):

In namespace are definted types (classes, strucutres, interfaces, ...) and the methods are in in types (not in delegates and enums).

The "Response" is not the class (however HttpWebResponse is). The line `Response.Redirect("ErrorPage.aspx.aspx?Error=" + READERROR);` looks like from code in class derived from `System.Web.UI.Page`. In this class is property named `Response` and for using this property you will need no using.

However the HttpWebResponse is in:

Namespace:  System.Net

Assembly:  System (in System.dll)